# Converting PDF to DOCX without any change in format

Tags: java, pdf

I a trying to convert my PDF file which has tables to DOCX type . When I try to convert it, I am getting the output only as plain text. How to convert the entire PDF which has tables into DOCX without any change in format ? I tried using JAVA and here is the snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Document converted started");
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        String pdf = "C:\\Users\\30216\\Desktop\\wordtopdf\\sample_full.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            TextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.processContent(i,
                    new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            String text = strategy.getResultantText();
            XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
            run.setText(text);
            run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\30216\\Desktop\\wordtopdf\\pdftoword.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("Document converted successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'pdf with tables'?

Comment: @ itmar green: PDF containing table elements i.e., PDF file having tables

Comment: You cant with TextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.processContent(i,
                    new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());  You have to develop your own extraction strategy in order to mantain formatting

Comment: @ AMB: Is there any alternative approach ? Is it possible in Python to convert PDF to DOCX ?

Comment: I recommend you documents4j, im using it for docx->pdf but its works pdf->docx too. Its java http://documents4j.com/#/

Comment: @AMB: I tried and it worked for me. It is possible to convert pdf to docx using document4j

Comment: Good to know, congratulations! @Abhinav Karthick